# Complete Beginner re Android Getting Started Training

Tags: android, methods

Sorry to ask but I am stuck on the "starting another activity" page of http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

I didnt know where else to ask...

I have copied everything exactly as told yet I keep getting an error..
The code that is causing the problem is  the method following the comment /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}   

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

When I to run the code I get a warning to fix the errors.. There are red xs beisde that last chunk of code BUT it is the exact same as the code in the lesson (i copied and pasted it over) .. I hope someone can help me with this... I cannot understand what I have done wrong.

Comment: Where are the errors exactly in your code. What lines does it say is bad (and we might need to know the exact errors as well)

Comment: Please post the error messages and we will be glad to explain what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

Are you copy - DisplayMessageActivity.class and creat activity_display_message layout?
You need also add Activity to manifest and Project->clean;

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to define EXTRA_MESSAGE variable, probably a final static String. Then, please make sure that you have a layout file named 'activity_main.xml', an EditText field with an ID of 'edit_message' and menu file named main.xml.

Comment: I am lost...as a beginner I must say I find the "Getting Started" tutorial from android (for me at least) not very user friendly.. I believe I am following the instructions to the letter but I must be making mistakes...I will keep trying BUT perhaps someone could recommend a more user friendly tutorial for a complete beginner..?